# Rsync log parser

Tags: rsync, logparser

What would be a good tool to parse rsync server daemon log files?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl has a module for [Rsync client logs](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man3/RoPkg::Rsync::LogParser.3pm.html)
 perhaps the server logs can be parsed in a similar fashion?